# Easily switching between connection strings in .NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dapper

I've got a code base that uses EF Core *and* Dapper to perform actions on a database.
I want to set up a new copy of the site to develop some features and I want this site to connect to a new isolated copy of the database (`dbConnectionDEBUG`).

At the moment, I use the following setup:

**startup.cs**

```
...
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbConnectionMain")));

services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
...
```

I have a `ConnectionStrings` class which is being populated correctly via the DI in startup:

```
public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string dbConnectionMain { get; set; }
    public string dbConnectionDEBUG { get; set; }

    public ConnectionStrings()
    {
        this.dbConnectionMain = "";
        this.dbConnectionDEBUG = "";
    }
}
```

Then, throughout my controllers/services I have access to `ConnectionStrings` and 99% of the time I'm doing the following to make DB calls:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionStrings.dbConnectionMain))
{
    conn.Open();
    ...
```

This would amount to a lot of code changes if I were to want to switch over to the 'DEBUG' db.

How do I easily switch between the connection strings in my code depending on what version of the system I'm working on.
If I could somehow do this dynamically that'd be great. The obvious determining factor would be the URL the site is operating on.

Alternatively, (as a single change) do I just manually change the connection string at the source (e.g keystore/appsettings). I'm not keen on this as it leaves room for human error.

---

## Update (2)

Based on what @Nkosi mentioned I am pursuing this path:

- Have one connection string 'Id' (i.e. `dbConnection`) used throughout
- Differentiate the connection string *value* within this based on the environment the app is running/deployed in

I have another question:

If I have the following...

```
"MYAPPNAME": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12345/;https://myapptestdomain.com/"
}
```

and:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        IHostingEnvironment env = context.HostingEnvironment;

        config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json", optional: true);
        
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

...will this automatically pick up my site is in the `Development` mode based on the `applicationUrl` values OR will I have to manually add `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with a value `Development` on the server I deploy the app to?

Additional: My app is running in an Azure App Service.

---

## Update (3) - Mission Complete

Just to finalise this question (in case anyone needs to know this), I have the following setup based on recommendations made by @Nkosi.

- Connection String - I have one connection string Id/name `dbConnection` which is used in all appSettings (see below)
- App Settings

  - I have a default `appSettings.json` with `dbConnection` that looks at the live database
  - I have an additional `appSettings.Playground.json` file with `dbConnection` that looks at my testing database
- Azure - App Service - On my `playground` development slot I have added an App Setting for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT with the value 'Playground'
- In my `Program.cs` file I have:

`config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true,reloadOnChange: true);`

and

`config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json", optional: true,reloadOnChange: true);`

Just to note, I do also initialise a Vault on Azure which stores all my Keys and Secrets for the Azure based apps. Locally `User Secrets` is used.

Comment: You could try using environment value to set the connection string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Comment: @Nkosi  - thanks. I will read up about that

Comment: @Nkosi I've added an update above in the OP. Just one more question :)

Comment: you will need to make an adjustment to that update

Comment: @Nkosi as in add `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as `Development` to my azure app config?

Comment: Hold on trying to draft up an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ASP.NET Core reads the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT at app startup and stores the value in `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName`.

Since the environment is being loaded, then it should be available from the hosting environment via the builder context

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => {
        string environment = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName; //get current environment

        //load config based on environment.
        config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true);
        //...
    })
    //...
```

#### Reference [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

Comment: Thanks,I did actually have that available but simplified it for my answer. So, the only thing I'm not sure is - will this pick up based on the URL or do I need to add in `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to my Azure App Service Settings?

Comment: @scgough based on `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

Answer (score 0):

For simple apps and to keep the connection strings away from my repository I use preprocessor statements plus PATH/System Variables and for release I provide a connection string within the settings.json.

```
#define USE_FEATURE_X
using System;

namespace MyNamespace {
    internal static class StaticConnectionStringFactory {
        public static string GetConnectionString() {
#if DEBUG && !USE_FEATURE_X
            var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CNNSTR_SQL_XYZ", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
#elif DEBUG && USE_FEATURE_X
            var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CNNSTR_SQL_ABC", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
#else
            var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
#endif
            return connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add 2 connection for debug and main then you will have face some difficulty because more member working in you team. may be some own wrongly use release mode for code development.

you can try this webconfig method:

public class ConnectionStrings
    {
        public string dbConnection { get; set; }

```
    public ConnectionStrings()
    {
        bool Ismain = bool.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HasLive"]);
        if (Ismain)
        {
            dbConnection = "";// get Main connectionstring
        }
        else
        {
            dbConnection = "";// get Debug connectionstring
        }

    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="dbConnectionMain" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="dbConnectionDEBUG" connectionString="" roviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
  <add key="HasLive" value="false"/>  
</appSettings>
</connectionStrings>
```